# VLOOKUP + PIVOT TABLE DATA

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vlookup

**OBJECTIVE**

Given a group of Clients, group each client into "discount" buckets based off of annual sales.

**SETUP**

- Pivot Table with Customer Name, Annual Sales
- Table with pricing categories (Bronze, Silver, Gold)

**APPROACH**

VLOOKUP(ANNUAL SALES, PRICING[ALL],2) - if a client exceeds a certain threshold in the PRICING table, they'll be listed as the corresponding PRICING bucket (e.g "GOLD").

**ISSUES/QUESTIONS**

1. VLOOKUP doesn't work well with pivot tables, especially if I collapse parent categories in excel. Is there a way to create a calculation field (that works with the pivot table, regardless whether or not parent categories are collapsed/hidden) that will essentially perform a VLOOKUP on a pricing table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

By using VLOOKUP and SUMIFS, I was able to develop a formula that would:

1. Create Pricing Categories
2. Categorize Customer purchases based off of three attributes (e.g
   customer, Product, Configuation) and sum revenue
3. Categorize Pricing Tier based on total revenue spent

**FORMULA**

```
=VLOOKUP(SUMIFS(Sales Revenue, Client ID, Product, Configuration),PRICING TABLE, PRICING TIER, TRUE)
```

The Formula sums all Sales revenues that match the Client's ID, Product, and the Product's configuration (e.g Total Revenue per Client, per Product). The VLOOKUP formula uses this value and compares against a pricing table.

Comment: Please can you accept this as answer so it is closed off.

Answer (score 0):

There is the function `GetPivotData` which is very powerful to use.

Have a look at this: [GetPivotData formula (Contextures)](http://www.contextures.com/xlPivot06.html#Formula)

Bear in mind that the structure of the PivotTable needs to be stable, else you may get unexpected results.

You can also use `INDEX / MATCH` to get data from PivotTables, advantage of index/match is that you can use the row data as well as the value fields (whereas GetPivotData is limited to value fields).